# Swagger/Swashbuckle - JSON does not correspond with the XML schema

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, swagger, swagger-ui, swashbuckle

I've got an ASP.NET MVC WebAPI configured to use OWIN to create the documentation. 
After i executed the application for the first time i realized that the Json file is not reflecting the changes that is saved in the XML file. Any new alteration or/and addition i made on the API controller is not reflected on the Json file, only on the XML file.
I've already tried change the versions of the packages installed, change the Swagger configuration file, cleaning the browser's cache, change browser but nothing seems to resolve the problem.

I'm using the following packages: Swashbuckle, Swashbuckle.Core and Swashbuckle.OData.Core.

EDIT:
SwaggerConfig Register Method:

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration _config)
    {
        _config.EnableSwagger(x =>
        {
            x.SingleApiVersion("v1", "NexoCS.Nexo.WebApi");
            x.IncludeXmlComments(() => new XPathDocument(string.Format(@"{0}\bin\ApiDoc.xml", AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory)));
            x.DescribeAllEnumsAsStrings();
            x.PrettyPrint();
            x.RootUrl(req => req.RequestUri.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority) +
                             req.GetRequestContext().VirtualPathRoot.TrimEnd('/'));
            x.UseFullTypeNameInSchemaIds();
            x.OAuth2("OAuth2")
                .Description("OAuth2 Implicit Grant")
                .Flow("implicit")
                .TokenUrl("/token")
                .Scopes(scopes =>
                {
                    scopes.Add("read", "Read access to protected resources");
                    scopes.Add("write", "Write access to protected resources");
                });
            x.CustomProvider(defaultProvider => new ODataSwaggerProvider(defaultProvider, x, _config));
        })
        .EnableSwaggerUi(y => 
        {
            y.EnableOAuth2Support("sampleapi", "samplerealm", "Swagger UI");
            y.EnableDiscoveryUrlSelector();
        });
    }
```

Startup.cs:

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        AutoMapperConfig.Config();

        new ApiConfig(app)
            .ConfigureCorsMiddleware(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["cors"])
            .ConfigureFormatters()
            .ConfigureExceptionHandling()
            .ConfigureSwagger()
            .ConfigureAuth()
            .ConfigureIoc()
            .ConfigureRoutes()
            .UseWebApi();
    }
```

ConfigureSwagger in ApiConfig:

```
    private readonly HttpConfiguration _configuration;
    private readonly IAppBuilder _app;

    public ApiConfig(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        if (app == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(app));
        _app = app;
        _configuration = new HttpConfiguration();        
    }

public ApiConfig ConfigureSwagger()
    {
        SwaggerConfig.Register(_configuration);
        return this;
    }
```

Comment: Can you show us your Swagger config?  How are you telling it to read the XML docs?

Comment: Just added the codes

Comment: Are you sure you dont have an old XML somewhere? Maybe due to different build settings?

Comment: @Stefan I have searched the entire solution folder and didn't find any duplicates of the XML file. I uncheck 'XML Documentation File' in the solution properties too but it loads an outdated XML file anyways.

Comment: This issue is very specific to your project, can you create a sample on github reproducing your issue, then post a link here.

Comment: If I had to guess your `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory` is not where you think it is (solution folder) debug and see where that is pointing to

Comment: @HelderSepulveda AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory is actually pointing to the correct directory.

Comment: Do you have a sample project on github reproducing your issue?

Comment: @HelderSepulveda Not in the moment, i'll create one tomorrow.

Comment: do a Clean, delete all existing bin / obj folders, delete temp files from AspNet folder and rebuild